# Is there a cross-browser JavaScript framework that supports old browsers like IE 5?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, frameworks, cross-browser, internet-explorer-5

I’m looking for my application (it’s a sort of CRM) to include a web-based GUI that supports old browsers like IE 5.

Is there any good client-side cross-browser framework that supports old browsers? I don’t need something fancy with effects and animations.

Thanks.

Comment: javascriptframework? "i don't need something fancy with effects and animations" --> what do you need then?

Comment: [ActiveWidgets](http://www.activewidgets.com/general.faq/supported-browsers.html) and [GlowJS](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2009/07/glow_technical_overviwe.html) support IE5.5 and Safari 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your specific needs check out David Mark's "[My Library](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html)". It doesn't have the popularity of jQuery or Extjs but for absolute cross-platform portability, nothing beats it. It was developed from best practices gathered from comp.lang.javascript.

He claims:

> ...after spending a week testing, I am pleased to
>   announce that Cinsoft supports My Library in the following browsers:
>
> All of them.
>
> But seriously, we've tested successfully in:-
>
> - IE 5-8
> - FF 1-3.5
> - Safari 2-4
> - Opera 5-10
> - Netscape 3-9

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think that’s a problem anyone’s interested in solving (i.e. web-based gui frameworks for older browsers like IE 5).

It’s much harder on older browsers because they lack features, have more bugs, and run JavaScript slower. And there’s less point, because those browsers are disappearing.

If I were you, I’d build a CRM application that’s **so good**, companies still on IE 5 will install Firefox just to use it.

Comment: -1 For the facebook & youtube crowd, yes you can think this way. But for developing enterprise solutions you should be aware that the *majority* of *big-paying-customers* out there are still on very old browsers and usually have IT departments that disallow installing other browsers. That's the *majority*, not _minority_. It's only safe to have this opinion if you're not working in the Enterprise market or don't care about making money.

Comment: Bull. Make the world’s best CRM application. Sell it to all the companies that aren’t stupid enough to think IE 5’s a good idea. Companies that remain that stupid will eventually die off. Majorities are just minorities that got popular.

Comment: This is a sexy opinion but not very practical. For instance healthcare organizations in the USA are known for being very outdated. Most of their systems still run on IE7 because their EHR was developed 40 years ago. So a system upgrade of that scale is too expensive.

Like @slebetman said, if you're selling software to a hospital then supporting old browsers is must, not an option.

Comment: @FrenchMajesty I’d be fascinated to know the details (feels like something that might get solved with cheap modern laptops running Windows XP in a virtual machine for IE 7-dependent systems), but sure, there are always obsolete legacy systems to support. In that scenario, I suspect it would be wise to design accordingly (avoid trying to replicate a desktop-like GUI in IE 7), and charge accordingly (a lot).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The problem is even the cheapest laptop multiplied by 100000 unit becomes a million dollar budge itemt. Most organisations don't have that kind of budget (with the exception of the US military). The problem is not outdated software, the problem is the cost of upgrading hardware (eg. getting new computers for every school in the state). The **ONLY** practical way of dealing with this while also dealing with voters not willing to pay more taxes to fund the upgrades is to upgrade piecemeal - one department or one office at a time...

Comment: ...  Whie you're doing that your software still need to support the entire state or country. Big companies with thousands of employees (eg. McDonalds or Exxon Mobil) also have similar problems only they tend to have an easier way to get the budget or they can completely outsource the work to 3rd party manpower vendors who can also supply the contract workers with computers

Comment: By now it wouldn't be IE7 but there are still systems out there relying on IE11 even though most people have moved on to Chrome or Edge. Systems to get upgraded but the upgrade cycle tend to be 5-10 years behind normal consumers. So now in 2024 you still need to support software from 2014 (which is actually more advanced than the software we were discussing when this answer was originally written in 2010)

Answer (score 1):

[DynAPI](http://dynapi.sourceforge.net/releases/dynapi-3.0.0-beta2/src/dynapi.js) and [lib.js](http://chipchapin.com/WebTools/JavaScript/Brattli_DHTML_Lib/showsource.php) are two of the oldest frameworks.  They support IE5 and Netscape browsers. There are [menu utilities](http://www.hallvord.com/opera/menus.htm) and [small abstraction libraries](http://www.scottandrew.com/weblog/dhtmllibs) as well.